# Display php date calculation, with a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, date-arithmetic

Trying to display "XX Year in the Industry" text on a CPT. The idea is that the client would enter the year the staff member started in a custom field and an automatic calculation would subtract that # from the current year and display.

The basic math is: Current year - Entered start year = Displayed year

This is almost working... but the calculation doesn't happen. The shortcode works, but not the calculation. Am I missing a filter? Do I maybe need 2 functions, one for the shortcode and one for the calc?

```
function YearsIndustry_shortcode($metadata, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
   $start_year = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ptb_start_year' );
   $current_year = new DateTime("now");
   $displayed_year = date_diff($current_year, $start_year)->y;
   $Years = $displayed_year. 'Years in Industry';
   return $Years;
}
add_shortcode('YII', 'YearsIndustry_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should retrieve the year from post_meta like this: `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ptb_start_year', true)`, otherwise you'll get array, not the single value.
2) To calculate the difference you should specify the certain date, not only the start year. If you'd like user to enter only the year, assuming that it's begin of the year (the 1st January), you should manually add day and month in your code.
3) In **date_diff** function you should use **DateTime** objects as parameters.

Summarizing all above, your code should look like:

```
function YearsIndustry_shortcode($metadata, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
    $start_year = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ptb_start_year', true );
    $start_date = new DateTime($start_year."-01-01");
    $current_date = new DateTime("now");
    $displayed_year = date_diff($current_date, $start_date)->y;
    $Years = $displayed_year. 'Years in Industry';
    return $Years;
}
```

But if you don't need to calculate precise difference, you may find the difference by substracting only years (**not recommended**):

```
function YearsIndustry_shortcode($metadata, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
    $start_year = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ptb_start_year', true );
    $current_year = date('Y');
    $displayed_year = $current_year - $start_year;
    $Years = $displayed_year. 'Years in Industry';
    return $Years;
}
```

Comment: why is the simple minus not recommended? Sadly it works ;)

Comment: @jzvestor , It's not recommended because it calculates not precise difference. For example, start date is 2015-12-12, the current date is 2017-05-04. It means that the company works only **1 complete year**. The 1st solution will return 1 year, but the 2nd solution will return 2 years.
If you don't need precise difference, you can freely use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

```
function YearsIndustry_shortcode() {
   $start_year = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ptb_start_year', true );
   $current_year = date('Y');
   $displayed_year = $current_year - $start_year;
   $Years = $displayed_year. ' Years in Industry';
   return $Years;
}
add_shortcode('YII', 'YearsIndustry_shortcode');
```